# Return a dictionary in excel using a csv for each column in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary by using a csv file in excel which returns a dictionary in each column by using the heading of each column, dictated in my code as col_list. I am having trouble becuase in the excel file provided, it only returns the headings, "happy" or "sad", as a dictionary and not the contents of the column, like so:

```
read('words.csv','sad')
{'a': [], 'd': [], 's': []}
```

Here is the link to view the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qJCvTQfAbk8Df4FrM4vy7GF71v6-dixGiBqx99kmps/edit?usp=sharing

My code:

```
import csv
def read(filename, col_list):
'''This function expects the name of a CSV file and a list of strings 
representing a subset of the headers of the columns in the file, and
returns a dictionary of the data in those columns'''

    with open('words.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader= csv.DictReader(f)
        dict1={}
        for col in col_list:
            dict1[col]=[]
        for row in reader:
            return dict1
```

(P.S. You may need to download the fie a csv in order to use it.)

Comment: The first problem you have is that you're using a string where you want a list of strings (`'sad'` instead of `[ 'sad' ]`).  there are other problems with your `read` function,  but this is the first one.  The next thing to consider is that if you call return inside a loop, it still only runs once (since it returns from the function the first time through the loop).  In Python, you may want to use '`yield`, but you might also want to investigate the append method of list objects.

Comment: The (a?) problem is on the last line of your script: `return` returns from the function immediately after reading the header row.

Comment: You got a dictionary with an empty list because that's all you ever put in the dictionary.  You need to decide what you want it to return and then figure out why you're not getting that.  Add that information to your question.

Comment: Ok. so how would I go about fixing that? Would I just use append after for row in reader? And then return outside of the loop?

Comment: @cco that information is in my question. It is the last sentence.

Comment: I know what your program does without downloading any data, but I still don't know what you want it to do.  Please show an example.

Comment: @cco Joab Mendes has it. Minus the issue that I ran into.

Comment: Yes, his code is fine.  Adding the output you expect to your question makes it a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question you want to create a dict that the keys are the headings of your file. And each key hold a list with the column content as items. To do so, your code can be like this:

```
import csv


def read_csv(filename, col_list):
    """This function expects the name of a CSV file and a list of strings
    representing a subset of the headers of the columns in the file, and
    returns a dictionary of the data in those columns, as described below."""

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # Better covert reader to a list (items represent every row)
        reader = list(csv.DictReader(f))
        dict1 = {}
        for col in col_list:
            dict1[col] = []
            # Going in every row of the file
            for row in reader:
                # Append to the list the row item of this key
                dict1[col].append(row[col])

    return dict1


print(read_csv(filename='words.csv', col_list=['happy', 'sad']))
```

The output of this code was:

```
{'sad': ['abominable', 'abominably', 'abominate', 'abomination', 'abort', 'aborted', 'aborts', 'abrade', 'abrasive', 'abrupt', 'abruptly', 'abscond', 'absence', 'absent-minded', 'absentee', 'absurd', 'absurdity', 'absurdly', 'absurdness', 'abuse', 'abused', 'abuses', 'abusive', 'abysmal', 'abysmally', 'abyss', 'accidental', 'accost', 'accursed', 'accusation', 'accusations', 'accuse', 'accuses', 'accusing', 'accusingly', 'acerbate', 'acerbic', 'acerbically', 'ache', 'ached', 'aches', 'aching', 'acrid', 'acridly', 'acridness', 'acrimonious', 'acrimoniously', 'acrimony', 'adamant', 'adamantly', 'addict', 'addicted', 'addicting', 'addicts', 'admonish', 'admonisher', 'admonishingly', 'admonishment', '', 'OF', 'WELL-BEING', 'ASSURANCE', 'A', 'REASON', 'FOR', 'BEING', 'ACARONAR', 'ACCOMMODATIVE', 'ALTITUDINARIAN', 'AMAZING', 'WORDS', 'AMIABLY', 'ACCOLADE', 'ACUMEN', 'ADJUSTABLE', 'ADMIRER', 'ADMIRING', 'ADMIRINGLY', 'ADORER', 'ADROIT', 'ADROITLY', 'ADULATED', 'ADULATION', 'ADULATORY', 'ADVENTURESOME', 'ADVOCATED', 'AMBITIOUS', 'AMBITIOUSLY', 'AMELIORATE', 'AMENITY', 'AMITY', 'AMPLY', 'AMUSE', 'AMUSINGLY', 'APOTHEOSIS', 'ASSUME', 'YOUR', 'OWN', 'VALUE', 'ASTONISHINGLY', 'ASTONISHMENT', 'ATTRIBUTIONAL', 'STYLE', 'QUESTIONNAIRE', '(ASQ)', 'AUTHENTIC', 'HAPPINESS', 'AWAKEN', 'AWAKENING', ''], 'happy': ['ADORED', 'ADORING', 'ADORINGLY', 'ADVANCED', 'ADVANTAGEOUS', 'ADVANTAGEOUSLY', 'ADVANTAGES', 'AFFABILITY', 'AFFABLY', 'AFFINITY', 'AFFIRMATION', 'AFFIRMATIVE', 'AFFLUENCE', 'AFFLUENT', 'AFFORD', 'AFFORDABLE', 'AFFORDABLY', 'AGILE', 'AGILELY', 'AGREEABLENESS', 'AGREEABLY', 'ALIGNED', 'ALL', 'IS', 'WELL', 'ALLURING', 'ALLURINGLY', 'ALTERNATIVE', 'HEALING', 'ALTRUISTICALLY', 'AMAZE', 'AMAZEMENT', 'AMAZES', 'AMAZINGLY', 'AMIABILITY', 'AMICABILITY', 'AMICABLE', 'AMICABLY', 'AMUSING', 'APPEAL', 'APPEALING', 'APPLAUD', 'APPRECIABLE', 'APPRECIATED', 'APPRECIATES', 'APPRECIATION', 'OF', 'BEAUTY', 'APPRECIATIVELY', 'APPROPRIATE', 'APPROVAL', 'APPROVE', 'ARDOR', 'ART', 'OF', 'APPRECIATION', 'ART', 'OF', 'STILLNESS', 'ART', 'OF', 'WELL-BEING', 'ASSURANCE', 'A', 'REASON', 'FOR', 'BEING', 'ACARONAR', 'ACCOMMODATIVE', 'ALTITUDINARIAN', 'AMAZING', 'WORDS', 'AMIABLY', 'ACCOLADE', 'ACUMEN', 'ADJUSTABLE', 'ADMIRER', 'ADMIRING', 'ADMIRINGLY', 'ADORER', 'ADROIT', 'ADROITLY', 'ADULATED', 'ADULATION', 'ADULATORY', 'ADVENTURESOME', 'ADVOCATED', 'AMBITIOUS', 'AMBITIOUSLY', 'AMELIORATE', 'AMENITY', 'AMITY', 'AMPLY', 'AMUSE', 'AMUSINGLY', 'APOTHEOSIS', 'ASSUME', 'YOUR', 'OWN', 'VALUE', 'ASTONISHINGLY', 'ASTONISHMENT', 'ATTRIBUTIONAL', 'STYLE', 'QUESTIONNAIRE', '(ASQ)', 'AUTHENTIC', 'HAPPINESS', 'AWAKEN', 'AWAKENING']}
```

I hope it helps. Also, take a look at the [ReadDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) documetation. ;)

Comment: @Suzaku Checkout if the filename is correct  (same as it is passed: 'words.csv') and if you passed the right arguments to the function. I ran the code before I answered you and it's fine. (I even gave the output you want haha)